# Netlify - Permission denied on my build executable

Tags: build, content-management-system, netlify

Netlify build command is - ./litepub build.

I'm getting exit code 126 with this error -

`/usr/local/bin/build: line 32: ./litepub: Permission denied.`

Is this a Github or Netlify problem? The exe is for linux systems. This exe was uploaded after I gave Netlify permission to access my repo. I don't think this has anything to do with the error? The exe is in the root of my repo just like the Netlify docs say.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'll need to make it executable.  Try changing your build command to `chmod a+x ./litepub && ./litepub` and I think it will work well, as long as your executable is compiled to work on 64bit linux, with ubuntu version 14.04 for best results.